# Fitting multiple charts in one view without scrolling HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, plotly

I want to show the first chart a little bigger and all following charts together in one window so no scrolling is involved. Later this would be displayed on a bigger screen so everything will be viewable. How can I do this?
Here's my current page layout: [Current(Needs scrolling to view everything)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rk0d.png)

And here is the layout I need: [Requirement(No scrolling is needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKVx.png)

I'm using AngularJS along with HTML.

I'm a novice at HTML, CSS, Angular and JS so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the reason other people have downvoted your question is because you have not posted enough code and you're asking people to do your work for you. If you have a current page layout, you should post more of the HTML, CSS, and Angular that you already have.

Comment: ok I will add the code thanks

Comment: you should be able to do one `$scope.drawChart` and pass the data into it.  Have a look at some stuff on services passing data to controllers in Angular.

Comment: ok I will check it out, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the boxes layout you have suggested, you would be better off with tabs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pane">
    <h3>Plotly charts</h3>
    <ul class="tabrow">
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
            ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}"
            ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mainView">
        <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewOne" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="plotlyChart"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="two.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewTwo" class="tabcontent">
       <div id="plotlyChart_1"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="three.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewThree" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="plotlyChart_2"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="four.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewFour" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="plotlyChart_3"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="four.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewFour" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="plotlyChart_4"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

etc

**CSS**

```
/* tabs */
.tabrow {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tabrow li {
  margin: 0 3px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #424a52;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabrow li.active {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

.tabrow {
  position: relative;
}
.tabrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424a52;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabrow:before {
  z-index: 1;
}
.tabrow li {
    position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #424a52;
    border-top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #424a52;
    padding: 0.75em;
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
     .controller('perspectivesCtrl',
['$rootScope', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$routeParams', '$log', '$timeout', '$http', 'getMessages',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, $routeParams, $log, $timeout, $http, getMessages) {

        $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'One',
            url: 'one.tpl.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Two',
            url: 'two.tpl.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Three',
            url: 'three.tpl.html'
        }];

        $scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

        $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
        }

        $scope.isActiveTab = function (tabUrl) {
            return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
        }
    }])
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, I have added my full code, can you see it?

Comment: my code should still work with your code, you just need to wrap my tabs solution around your code

Answer (score 0):

To lay it out with boxes in a responsive way, try something this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="pane">
    <h3>Plotly charts</h3>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="two-col">
            <div class="chart-box">
                <div id="plotlyChart"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chart-box">
                <div id="plotlyChart_1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-col">
        <div id="plotlyChart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**
You will need to adjust the column-widths and the number of column classes to fit the design of your page.

```
/* responsive grid */

.page-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box,
.chart-box
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.box h3 {
    padding: 3px;
}

.one-col {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-table;
}

.two-col {
    width: 97%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner-box {
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Comment: I added my code so you can check it to get a better idea of what I did

Comment: I did it, I used this code:

#images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    right: 0px;
    }
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 700px;
  min-width: 750px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
.one {
 flex-grow: 2;
}

Comment: if you use `position-absolute`, it might not be responsive in different screen resolutions, but other than that, that makes sense

Comment: So should I use relative instead of absolute? And my code works but it still too big for my current screen resolution of 1080p. Maybe t will show fully without the needing to scroll on the company display of 42 inches

edit: Absolute was only for images and when I did relative, the image was overlapped.

Comment: Don't use the `position` property at all. You need to make your design work on a number of different screen resolutions, so you should use either percentage widths or `vw`

Comment: on a large screen, you can have the layout you wanted, but on a smaller screen, you want the boxes to wrap around. That's why I suggested using `flex-wrap`.

Comment: you will also need to make your Plotly charts scale appropriately - so give them either percentage widths or `vw` as well.  https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/